# Rewrite Javascript Function using Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm stuck with updating my code to use promises now.

The hash function is working, but changed. It now returns a promise and not a value anymore. And I don't know how to use it :-(

```
function hash(input) {
    // transform the input into an arraybuffer.
    let buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode( JSON.stringify(input) );

    return window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", buffer).then( (hash)=> {
        return btoa(String.fromCharCode( ...new Uint8Array(hash) ));
    });
}
```

This is the function that needs to be rewritten. hash(...) is called several times.

```
function update(){

    // array of Objects (empty to simplify my question)
    let data = [{}, {}, {}];


    // if data has changed => process it
    if( hash(data) !== hash(previousData) ){

        // clone for next time comparison (before calculating hashes!)
        previousData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); // simple deepclone 

        data.forEach( item=>{
            // reset dynamic values within a cloned item for simple item comparison checks  
            item.id = hash( Object.assign( {}, item, {dynValue:1}) ); 

            //complet item hash including dynamic values
            item.hash = hash( item );
        });

        // fire event with changed data array
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm basically creating two hashes for each object within the array to simplify later comparison. One with some ignored properties (reset to default values) and one for the complete object.

Thank you for helping me out

Comment: I suggest you don't return a promise from the `hash` function since the rest of your code is based on the premise that you aren't. Just wait for the promise to be resolved and return the actual result.

Comment: @apokryfos How would you rewrite the hash function to return the value? window.crypto.subtle.digest just returns a promise.

Comment: Could probably find an alternative lib that returns a value. Maybe http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to try and preserve the direct nature of the hash function call since changing it will require such a big rewrite, however in the absence of this you could probably do something like Promise...then chains.

```
function update() {
    //Same code 
    Promise.all([hash(data), hash(previousData)]), then(values => {
        if (values[0] !== values[1]) {
            //Same code
            var promiseChain = [];
            data.forEach(item=> {
                promiseChain.push(
                        Promise.all([
                                hash(Object.assign({}, item, {dynValue:1})),
                                hash(item)
                        ]).then(values=> {
                            item.id = values[0];
                            item.hash = values[1];
                        })
                );
            });
            Promise.all(promiseChain).then(/* fire event with changed data array */);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, it works and I learned something about nesting Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Your in the comparison has to change because you're now writing asynchronous code. The comparison has to wait until both calls to `hash` resolve.

Example code:

```
var hash = hash(data);
var hashPrev = hash(previousData);

hash.then((hashVal) => {
   hashPrev.then((hashPrevVal) => {
      if (hashVal == hashPrevVal) doFurtherLogicHere();
   });
});
```